# Can I install ubuntu on USB with pendrivelinux WITHOUT touching my laptops HDD / Boot ?MBR etc?

Tags: 14.04, windows-7, usb-drive, persistence

I want to install Ubuntu 14.04LTS with persistence on my 32GB USB Flash drive, probably using PendriveLinux). The question is that I will do it on a borrowed laptop and since I want to use this flash drive on different systems, I don't want it to touch the underlying system. I want to make sure that pendrivelinux will NOT install GRUB or touch the laptop's MBR while installing ubuntu on the flash drive.

Does anyone know if pendrivelinux (or any similar tool) can do that without messing with the current operating system?

(Note that I cannot open the laptop to unplug the HDD)

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

If you are simply using pendrivelinux to create an Ubuntu LiveUSB it will not make any changes to the laptops hard drive. You can still use Ubuntu by booting from the USB drive if you make it using pendrivelinux. You will also have an option to choose how much space to use for persistance